# Trying to find a way to build custom graphical reports in VB 6

Tags: database, vb6, reporting

Does anyone know of a db reporting tool for VB 6.0 that would allow me to create a graphical chart in this type of tree format?

I have looked through the documentation for MSChart control and for something called FusionCharts, and a couple others but I have not seen anything that does this.[image]

Comment: There used to be a number of structured drawing component libraries on the market.  I'm not aware of any current products but a search might turn some up.  Some are proprietary while others can save/load EMF/WMF formats.

Comment: This is a useful question. Did you ever get this to work? If so please accept or post an answer for how you did it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Access has a built in tree view control that can be used to display custom information, it can be built up from different types of data sources also; e.g XML.